# select a row based on another row in a data frame

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = 1:15, V2 = structure(c(5L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 
2L, 13L, 3L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 14L, 6L), .Label = c("A0A087WNY6", 
"B2RTL5", "B8JJX9", "D3Z2H7", "E9PZ97", "G3UWX1", "Q2VWQ4", "Q3TMB5", 
"Q3TWK2", "Q6ZPS9", "Q7TMW3", "Q8BP71", "Q8R4K2", "Q925B0", "Q9WU01"
), class = "factor"), V3 = c(5L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 15L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

I want to select the rows from the first two columns based on third column values

the expected output is this

```
5   Q6ZPS9
7   Q8R4K2
10  Q8BP71
11  Q9WU01
13  D3Z2H7
15  G3UWX1
```

Comment: @rawr the only things I tried was Anatta said, I tried many different ways but the problem was that it comes from a more complicated structure. so I managed to extract this from that data and make it simple. if you have any solution please shot ,

Comment: Oh sorry, I deleted it because it wasn't really general.  It was `na.omit(df)[3:2]`

Comment: @Richard Scriven thanks I liked it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel like `V3` should not be in this dataframe but a different vector. But here is a way

```
df[df$V1 %in% df$V3,1:2]
```

Comment: I liked your solution and it is definitely giving me the answer. I prefer to stay a bit more to just see what others will give (just to learn more) but your solution is simple, nice and fast thanks.